# Networkx : getting all possible paths in DAG

Tags: python, graph, networkx, directed-graph

I am trying to split a directed (acyclic) graph into direction-connected path, relying on *connectivity* :

[image: Example graph]

When I test weak and strong connectivity subgraphs, here is what I get :

```
Weak connectivity :
['16', '17'], ['3', '41', '39', '42']
Strong connectivity :
['17'], ['16'], ['39'], ['41'], ['3'], ['42']
```

I understand the weak connectivity result, but not the strong-connectivity one, as I would expect 3 subgraphs : [16, 17], [42, 39] and [3, 41, 39].

What am I missing here, why those single node lists ? How to get the expected result ?

Here is the code :

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('16', '17'), ('3', '41'), ('41', '39'), ('42', '39')])

print("Weak connectivity : ")
for subgraph in (G.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.weakly_connected_components(G)) :
    print(subgraph.nodes)
print("Strong connectivity : ")
for subgraph in (G.subgraph(c).copy() for c in nx.strongly_connected_components(G)) :
    print(subgraph.nodes)

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.circular_layout(G))
plt.show()
```

Comment: A strongly connected component is defined as a subgraph such that there exists a path from any node to any other node. The answer given by networkx is correct. Perhaps you are looking for something else?

Comment: Well, then [16, 17] would be a strongly connected subgraph, as you can reach 17 from 16, no ? Or would you also need to be able to reach 16 from 17 ?

Comment: What I try to achieve it to get all possible full directed paths in this graph, so I would get [16, 17], [42, 39] and [3, 41, 39] from my example.

Comment: [16,17] is not strongly directed because there is no path from 17 to 16.

Comment: There is no such thing as "full directed path." Unless you formally define it, you cannot calculate it. What if there are two more edges (2,41) and (41,4). How would the expected output change?

Comment: Sorry about this, it seems that I don't have a clear definition of what I am looking for. By adding 2 nodes & 2 edges as you suggested, that would indeed change the expected output to this : [16, 17], [42, 39], [3, 41, 39], [3, 41, 4], [2, 41, 39] and [2, 41, 4].
In my mind it is something like "all complete paths, considering the fact that edges are oriented". I don't want path [2, 41] in my output, since longer paths exist.

Comment: (I now realize how this has nothing to do with connectivity, I made up my mind on cases that were too specific. I will edit my post once I know what I am truly looking for)

Comment: Make sure you specify the expected output when there are two parallel paths (e.g., 1->2->3 and 1->2->4->5->3). There may be exponentially many combinations of paths.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191956/discussion-between-arkeen-and-dyz).

Comment: probably [all_simple_paths](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html) will help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, thanks to comments & answers, I realised that "connectivity" was a false lead for what I want to achieve. To be clear : **I want to get every possible path between all starting nodes to their connected ending nodes, in a directed acyclic graph**.

So I ended up writing my own solution, which is quite simple to understand, but probably not the best, regarding performance or style (pythonic / networkx). Improvment suggestions are welcome :)

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('16', '17'), ('3', '41'), ('41', '39'), ('42', '39')])

roots = []
leaves = []
for node in G.nodes :
  if G.in_degree(node) == 0 : # it's a root
    roots.append(node)
  elif G.out_degree(node) == 0 : # it's a leaf
    leaves.append(node)

for root in roots :
  for leaf in leaves :
    for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, leaf) :
      print(path)

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.circular_layout(G))
plt.show()
```

(If there is a built-in function in networkx, I clearly missed it)

Answer (score 3):

@Arkeen, Your solution looks very close to what is in the networkx documentation for `all_simple_paths`. It reads,

```py
    Iterate over each path from the root nodes to the leaf nodes in a
    directed acyclic graph passing all leaves together to avoid unnecessary
    compute::

        >>> G = nx.DiGraph([(0, 1), (2, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4)])
        >>> roots = (v for v, d in G.in_degree() if d == 0)
        >>> leaves = [v for v, d in G.out_degree() if d == 0]
        >>> all_paths = []
        >>> for root in roots:
        ...     paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, root, leaves)
        ...     all_paths.extend(paths)
        >>> all_paths
        [[0, 1, 3], [0, 1, 4], [2, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4]]
```

I think this works fine if there are only a few components in the graph. If the number of components is large, then this approach spends most of its time trying to connect roots to leaves that are in other components. But, still works.

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing is the definition of [strongly connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29):

> [A directed graph] is strongly connected, diconnected, or simply
>   strong if it contains a directed path from u to v and a directed path
>   from v to u for every pair of vertices u, v. The strong components are
>   the maximal strongly connected subgraphs.

You have *no* strong connection between any two nodes of the graph shown, let alone the 3-node subgraph you list.  You can, indeed, traverse 3 -> 41 -> 39, but there is no path back to 41, let alone 3.  That graph is, therefore, *not* strongly connected.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition of strongly connected graph, the result you get is correct.

**DEFINITION: strongly connected graph**

A directed graph G=(V,E) is said to be strongly connected if every vertex v in V is reachable from every other vertex in V.